# Find and Replace Word Interop Whole Word Matching

Tags: c#, replace, ms-word, find, interop

What I am trying to do is write an application that can find & replace all occurrences of a given string within a Microsoft Word Document.

What I have chosen to do so far is use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word assembly.  It works, but not exactly how I'd like it to.  The problem is that it is matching substrings and replacing them.

Here is my code so far:

```
foreach (DataRow drCrossWalkItem in dtCrossWalk.Rows)
{
    foreach (Word.Range myStoryRange in doc.StoryRanges)
    {
        myStoryRange.Find.MatchWholeWord = true;
        myStoryRange.Find.MatchPrefix = false;
        myStoryRange.Find.MatchSuffix = false;
        myStoryRange.Find.Text = drCrossWalkItem["strOldValue"].ToString();
        myStoryRange.Find.Replacement.Text = drCrossWalkItem["strNewValue"].ToString();
        myStoryRange.Find.Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
        myStoryRange.Find.Execute(Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
    }
}
doc.SaveAs2(strFinalPath);
doc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(doc);
```

So it works perfectly in most scenarios, but the issue I am having is in this following example:

```
Document Text:
test_item_one
test_item_one_two_three
```

Say I want to replace "test_item_one" with "hello" -- well in my current program, it replaces both lines like so:

```
Document Text:
hello
hello_two_three
```

Apparently matching "whole word" does not include _'s.  It is the same as if you were to try Find/Replace in Microsoft Word.  Any idea if there is another option to solve this particular scenario?

Comment: I have deleted my answer because of considering your attitude highly disrespectful and help-unworthy. Don't expect more help from me.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting following find property

```
myStoryRange.Find.MatchWildcards = false ;
```

Take a look at all of the Find members to see if you see any of them can help you solve the problem

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.interop.word.find_members.aspx**

Answer (score 0):

Not so much an answer but a way to help other people who are looking for details on Word wildcard matching like I was.
The documentation on it is scant, but I found this link which is for the javascript Office API also applies to VSTO:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/search-option-guidance

```
To find:                    Wildcard    Sample
Any single character        ?   s?t finds sat and set.
Any string of characters    *   s*d finds sad and started.
The beginning of a word     <   <(inter) finds interesting and intercept, but not splintered.
The end of a word           >   (in)> finds in and within, but not interesting.
One of the specified characters     [ ]     w[io]n finds win and won.
Any single character in this range  [-]     [r-t]ight finds right and sight. Ranges must be in ascending order.
Any single character except the characters in the range inside the brackets     [!x-z]  t[!a-m]ck finds tock and tuck, but not tack or tick.
Exactly n occurrences of the previous character or expression    {n}    fe{2}d finds feed but not fed.
At least n occurrences of the previous character or expression   {n,}   fe{1,}d finds fed and feed.
From n to m occurrences of the previous character or expression  {n,m}  10{1,3} finds 10, 100, and 1000.
One or more occurrences of the previous character or expression  @      lo@t finds lot and loot.
```